# How to kill chain of parent processes in python?

Tags: python

So I have a script which creates a child process with the Subprocess module.
This child process then also creates child processes and it can go on for a while. Is there any way to kill the entire chain of parent processes from a child process without knowing how deep in the chain it is?

i tried:

```
os.kill(os.getppid(), signal.SIGTERM)
```

but that only kills the direct parent of the child process. Id like to go all the way to the top of the chain and kill the processes coming down.